# what is a for loop doing on file objects?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a question related to Python for loops and files.

In this code:

```
file = raw_input("input a text file ")

f = open(file) #  creates a file object of file

for line in f:
    # prints each line in the file
    print line 



print f

# prints <open file 'MVL_ref.txt', mode 'r' at 0x0267D230>

print f.read() # same output of the for-cycle
print f.readline() # same output of the for-cycle
```

The for-loop is printing each line that is present in my text 
file. However, if I print the file object I get something totally different.
This puzzles me because I would expect that I had to use something like:

```
for line in f.read():
    print line
```

but of course this is not the case.
If I use the read or readline methods without a for-loop I get the same output of the for-loop.

Is the for-loop doing some magic like calling read() or readline() by default on the file object? I am learning how to code with python but I fell I don't really understand much of what the code is doing "behind my back".

Thank you for all the explanations that will come.

Comment: The comment says exactly what it is doing, doesn't it?

Comment: `for line in f.read():` ... Don't confuse your variable names. Those aren't lines, those are single characters

Comment: it actually depends what you have in txt file , if the lines are already seperated using newline character "\n" , then there will no need to use **.read()** method

Comment: You could [read over the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). Specifically down to the part *It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file objects*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since file object in Python is [iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable) you can iterate over it to get lines of file one-by-one.

However File is not a collection but object - you won't see all lines by printing this like when outputting collection

```
l = ["line1", "line2"]
print l
```

but you will see entity description

```
<open file 'path_to_the_file', mode 'r' at 0x0245D020>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So in other words, in case of the for-loop the file object behaves like a collection

Comment: Yes because it can return iterator that allows you to get lines one-by-one

Comment: Your last answer made me look for iterator, iterable, __iter__, next and other stuff. There is indeed a lot of stuff happening behind the loop which I totally ignored. Thank you man!

Comment: glad to help you :)